# Magento 2 : Upgrade Data Version of custom module using setup:db-data:upgrade

Tags: magento2, upgrade, setup-upgrade, data

I created a custom module which has below UpgradeData.php.

```
<?php

namespace Akhil\Database\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface {

    protected $newsFactory = '';

    public function __construct(\Akhil\News\Model\NewsFactory $newsFactory) {
        $this->newsFactory = $newsFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
        $data = [
            'news_title' => "News Title upgrade",
            'news_content' => "News content upgrade"
        ];
        $news = $this->newsFactory->create();
        $news->addData($data)->save();
        }
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.2', '<')) {
        $data = [
            'news_title' => "News Title upgrade 1",
            'news_content' => "News content upgrade 1"
        ];
        $news = $this->newsFactory->create();
        $news->addData($data)->save();
        }
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.3', '<')) {
        $data = [
            'news_title' => "News Title upgrade 2",
            'news_content' => "News content upgrade 2"
        ];
        $news = $this->newsFactory->create();
        $news->addData($data)->save();
        }

    }

}
```

Here is my module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Akhil_Database" setup_version="1.0.1" data_version="1.0.2" />
</config>
```

Now if I run below command:

```
php bin/magento setup:db-data:upgrade
```

It does not upgrade the data version. Even in the table setup_module I don't see upgraded version.

**Although, I am able to make my work done** by changing `setup_version="1.0.1"` to `setup_version="1.0.2"` and run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

But my question why `php bin/magento setup:db-data:upgrade` not working for me. What I am doing wrong here?

As per my knowledge:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade //To upgrade both schema and data 
>   php bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade //To upgrade only schema 
>   php bin/magento setup:db-data:upgrade //To upgrade only data